# Trying to pass an Id from my controller to my Apex class in setCallBack, but the debug logs show a null value

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Here is my **Javascript** **controller** code:

```
var action = cmp.get("c.getOpenCases");

    var userIdAction = cmp.get("c.getUserId");
    userIdAction.setCallback(this, function(response){
    var idstate = response.getState();
    if (idstate === "SUCCESS") {

        var id = response.getReturnValue();
        console.log(id);

        action.setParams({
            "contactId": id
        });
     }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(userIdAction);

    action.setCallback(this,function(resp){
    ----Many More lines of code--- };
```

Here is my **Apex Controller**:

```
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getOpenCases(String contactId){
        System.debug(contactId);
        return [SELECT Subject, Activity__c, Reason, Status FROM Case WHERE Status != 'Closed' AND ContactId =: contactId ];
    }
```

The system debug is showing null and the query returns zero results when I'm trying to assign id to 'contactId' in the setCallBack. The console.log(id) is also outputting the correct Contact ID as well. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due  order in which code statements are written.The setParams should be before you get into the callback

```
var action = cmp.get("c.getOpenCases");

//var userIdAction = cmp.get("c.getUserId");
action.setParams({
        "contactId": id
    });
action.setCallback(this, function(response){
var idstate = response.getState();
if (idstate === "SUCCESS") {

    var id = response.getReturnValue();
    console.log(id);


 }
});
$A.enqueueAction(action);
```

If you need multiple callbacks you can use callback or Promises as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm?search_text=promise)

Comment: This does not work because I need the contactId before I call for the list of cases. The reason I set the action inside the callback is because of the asynchronous behavior.